# Calculating EVI in ArcMap for Landsat 8 Image gives values ranging from 55155 to -23235

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, landsat-8, vegetation-index, evi

How do I calculate EVI in ArcMap for Landsat 8 Image?

My values are ranging from 55155 to -23235.

I have tried using the formula:

```
2.5 * [(band 5- band 4)/ (band 5 + 6*band 4-7.5* band 2) + 1]
```

I have tried to use various parentheses in and around the formula. It simply isn't working for the range of values from -1 to +1.

Comment: Please edit your question to specify *exactly* what landsat product you have and where you got it from.  Make sure your Landsat data is reflectance with values from 0.0-1.0.  If it is a reflectance product, but the values are integers 0 - thousands, then check the metadata for a scale factor.

Answer (score 1):

The correct [EVI formula](https://www.usgs.gov/land-resources/nli/landsat/landsat-enhanced-vegetation-index?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#qt-science_support_page_related_con) in raster calculator is as follows:

```
2.5 * ((Band 5 - Band 4) / (Band 5 + 6 * Band 4 - 7.5 * Band 2 + 1))
```

You need to replace the square brackets `[]` with normal brackets `()` in raster calculator. In addition, the link above explains that the formula should be applied on a surface reflectance processed image. If you don't have it, then follow the link above and it will explain how to process your Landsat 8 data for surface reflectance, then apply EVI.